# Does the default view on StackOverflow home page still have sense?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

The volume of questions/answers per minutes that StackOverflow has reached is impressive.

New questions fall down very quickly (15 minutes more or less)

I am wondering if the default view shown in home page has still meaning of would it be better present other type of data.

Comment: what "types of data" do you have in mind?

Comment: Unicorns.  Definitely Unicorns. Prancing Unicorns everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The home page on Stack Overflow (for users with accounts anyway) is now the [interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab.

This shows questions that are, hopefully, "interesting" to the user. That is one's with tags that the users has added to their interesting list and ones with tags that the user has recently viewed.

[This was changed in November 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: That was indeed an appreciated change to me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another suggestion for what the homepage should show?

Comment: Clearly it should be a list of recent answers sorted by users reputation.  Oh wait, sorry, that's for Jon Skeet Overflow, not Stack Overflow.