# SO main page is a victim of the site's success

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

The number of new questions being submitted on Stack Overflow means that a question only gets a few minutes to be spotted on the front page before being lost forever.
The unanswered questions link seems to show all questions without an accepted answer, and isn't in date order, so anything you missed before it left the main page is impossible to find.

How about adding:

1) A "today's questions" link to show all of a day's/the previous day's/a week's/&c. new questions.

2) A "more" link to show the "next screen" of questions that were pushed off the bottom.

3) Not displaying — at all — questions for ignored tags, to give more space for questions that you are interested in and will likely be able to answer.

I appreciate the sense of not having SO split into separate sites for each language/technology — but at the moment we are drowning in questions I have no interest in.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64714/does-the-default-view-on-stackoverflow-home-page-still-have-sense

Comment: I had a question get 4 views before it went away from the homepage once

Comment: Wait... I thought the "unanswered" page **was** sorted by date...?

Comment: @detly Only if you choose that option. If you go by "mytags" or "votes", it is not sorted by date.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I'm possibly unusual in being a regular user that goes to the frontpage (it's on my auto-open list) looks like I need to build a more customised experience

Comment: @detly, yes, but modification date, not post date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you want more or less already exists.

1) Click "Questions" near the top of the page (or just load https://stackoverflow.com/questions), sort by "newest" and go back in time 15/30/50 questions at a time

2) Do the above, jumping to page 2 if needed — the front page shows a mix of new and recently active questions, so it won't match exactly, but your question only asks about new questions, so this should work

3) Go to your profile, select the "prefs" tab and check "Hide Ignored Tags"

Comment: #3 thanks I didn't see that, must have missed it being added.

Comment: @mgb no problem, there wasn't a lot of fanfare when they rolled that feature out.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason you're not browsing by tag or tag combination?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

You can also click the questions link to browse questions in a static order

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

To me, this just means you need to be jumping off the homepage earlier into your specific [tag] areas of interest.

(At the time I'm writing this, the frontpage span is **9 minutes**.)

edit:
I increased the SO homepage questions from 48 to 96 many months ago. I am now instituting another temporary fix -- the homepage will contain from 96 (minimum) to 192 questions, ideally trying to display at *least* a 30 minute span from youngest question to oldest question.

At peak times there might be more than 192 questions asked in 30 minutes, unfortunately, but that's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: To add onto this, don't also forget that you can supplement either of these routes with the search queries of `hasaccepted:0` (only questions without accepted answers) and/or `answers:0` (only questions that haven't received any answers).

Comment: @grace I'm open to hearing ways we can improve the homepage as well, of course -- a nine minute span is not great

Comment: @Jeff On SO, maybe because of that speed, I don't use the homepage and rely on the questions sort. But I also consider that partly because I rely more on my interesting tags selection on SO than on Meta or Gaming (where I use the homepage for everything). So I don't know what improvements can help, but I imagine any fixes will simply improve convenience. But until such changes exist, I also enjoy providing any workarounds or options that people can use in the duration.

Comment: The 'questions' button always confused me - the front page of SO is questions - what is the 'questions' button for?

Comment: @ Grace Note - yes but realistically doing a search with "answers:0" everytime I visit SO just to see the new relevant questions that I might have missed implies something of a design fail.

Comment: @mgb The front page and the questions list operate differently. [Check here for a quick run through of the main differences](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/difference-between-active-top-questions-and-active-questions/50989#50989). But importantly, the front page is trimmed to only show one set of questions, and does not show very low scored posts.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for now. Going to the C# tagged page sorted by newest showed me a span of slightly under 2 hours @ 50/page, which is fine. The question is, will this solution need to be revisited later on when the site is even bigger?

Answer (score 2):

> The unanswered question link seems to show all questions without an accepted answer and isn't in date order so anything you missed when it left the first page is impossible to find.

---

[image]

Comment: So the questions shows the questions without answers and unanswered shows questions WITH answers?

Comment: @mgb It just happens that the 4 most recent new questions at the time of the screenshot have 0 answers. Without adding a filter like I mentioned in Jeff's post, it won't necessarily have that. Unanswered shows you questions specifically with no *upvoted* answers.